# Logical coordinates to device coordinates Opengl

Tags: opengl

anyone knows about OpenglGL calls (no extension or GLX) to convert from Logical coordinates to device coordinates? equivalent of Win32 LPtoDP function.

I am actually trying to compute the pixel width and height. I can do that from device coordinates width_in_pixels == northeast.x - northwest.x. but i need device coordinates.

Tricky part is I do not need to render anything on the screen? it is ok if I render to memory?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [`gluProject()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml).

It's all matrix math, so you don't need to render anything to the screen.